# Use the result of SelectSubQuery in a condition with NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate with IQueryOver to retrieve a `List<Message>`. Users can mark a `Message` as a favourite. Each `Message` has a property `public bool IsFavourite` which contains `true` when at least one `User` has marked that `Message` as their favourite.
So in my query I use `SelectSubQuery` to retrieve the number of times it was marked as favourite. So far so good. I also want to use the result from that subquery in a condition to set `IsFavourite`.

My query right now looks like this.

```
Message messageAlias = null;
MessageDTO messageDto = null;

var messages = GetSessionFactory().GetCurrentSession()
    .QueryOver<Message>(() => messageAlias)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => messageList.Id).WithAlias(() => messageDto.Id)
        .Select(() => messageList.Title).WithAlias(() => messageDto.Title)
        .SelectSubQuery(
            QueryOver.Of<UserMessageFavourite>()
            .Where(f => f.Message.Id == messageAlias.Id).ToRowCountQuery()).WithAlias(() => messageDto.FavouriteCount)
        )
    )
```

The property `MessageDto,FavouriteCount` is merely there so I can set the `IsFavourite` property. So what I would like to do is to use the SubQuery result in a condition and set the result of that condition to `IsFavourite` like `.SelectSubQuery(subquery.ToRowCountQuery()) > 0).WithAlias(() => messageDto.IsFavourite)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have `FavouriteCount` in your `MessageDTO` entity then you can just use readonly C# property like this:

```
class MessageDTO {
   //other properties
   public int FavouriteCount { get; set; }
   public bool IsFavorite => FavouriteCount > 0;
}
```

Otherwise you can use custom projection:

```
Message messageAlias = null;
MessageDTO messageDto = null;

var projection = Projections.Conditional(
     Subqueries.Exists(QueryOver.Of<UserMessageFavourite>()
                       .Where(f => f.Message.Id == messageAlias.Id).DetachedCriteria)),
     Projections.Constant(true),
     Projections.Constant(false));

var messages = GetSessionFactory().GetCurrentSession()
    .QueryOver<Message>(() => messageAlias)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => messageList.Id).WithAlias(() => messageDto.Id)
        .Select(() => messageList.Title).WithAlias(() => messageDto.Title)
        .Select(projection).WithAlias(() => messageDto.IsFavorite)
    )
```

Comment: Hi Roman, my goal was to remove the `FavouriteCount` property.
I solved this using your `Projections` example. thanks!